# Show full size image of the clicked grid image

Tags: java, android

Main Activity.java

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_grid);

    // populate data
    products = new ArrayList();
    products.add(new Product("http://image1.jpg"));
    products.add(new Product("http://image2.jpg"));
    products.add(new Product("http://image3"));
    products.add(new Product("http://image4"));

    //
    gvProducts = (GridView) findViewById( R.id.grid_products);
    adapterProducts = new ProductListAdapterWithCache(this, products);
    gvProducts.setAdapter(adapterProducts);




    gvProducts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


           String path = (MainActivity.this, position);

           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("IMAGEPATH",path);
           startActivity(intent);
           }
    });

}
```

I am developing simple image processing app in android studio. I am downloading images from the `url` to show in grid as above.. I want to show the full image in page when the grid is clicked.. trying to pass the position through intent but its showing error on this line..

```
String path = (MainActivity.this, position);
```

FullImageActivity.java

```
    public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image);
        // selected item
       int imageInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGEPATH", R.drawable.spinner);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       imageView.setImageResource(imageInt);

    }
}
```

I am a beginner so guide me if I have done anything wrong in the basics.

Thanks,

Comment: please show my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
gvProducts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("IMAGEPATH",products.get(position).imagePath);
           startActivity(intent);
           }
    });
```

In Activity:

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGEPATH");
```

Comment: Ofcourse it should not be there, just check your code again and check your method again.

Comment: here is my sample code, which is working perfect.
Intent intent = new Intent(UberTicketEventsListActivity.this, UberTicketOwnerEventFlyerActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("KEY", 0);
     startActivity(intent);

Comment: In the line `intent.putExtra("IMAGEPATH",products.get(position));` the problem lies with `products.get(position)` which will return the product object. But you need to pass the image path. So do it like `products.get(position).imagePath` where `imagePath` is your string variable in the Product object

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), refer to the example code in the PhotoView Project, and i also provide some code, hope this will help.

Java Code snippet:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.diary_imageview);

    imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(IMAGE_URL);

    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mPhotoView);
    mAttacher.setOnPhotoTapListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnPhotoTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPhotoTap(View view, float v, float v2) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, mPhotoView, Util.getDisplayImageOptions(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAttacher.update();
        }
    });

}
```

XML layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>

</merge>
```